# Using jquery to unhide a header 1/2 way down a page

Tags: jquery, header, sticky

I've done a search but I couldn't apply any of the answers I found.

I have a row and I can target it with #header with the following CSS attached to it:

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index:99;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
display: none;
}
```

I want to know how I can make this fade in at a certain point on the page, and fade back out when I scroll back up using jQuery.

Any help or point to relevant resources is appreciated.

So far I have this and I don't know what to add to it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: do you already have something to show (JS or at least an idea)?  
in the end its simple, adding an event listener on scroll and if scrollTop is x then header.hide()  
anyway without at least an idea or a start of code it would be like - i have a task at work - lets ask stackoverflow!? ;)

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        
    });

This is as far as my research has taken me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery `scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

For example:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 100 && scroll < 300){
                $('#header').fadeOut();
            }

            if (scroll > 300){
                $('#header').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```